# Is there a better way to remove duplicate values on multiple properties in a List?

Tags: c#, performance, list, morelinq

Trying to remove duplicates from a list where a duplicate is when either the first, the second or both properties are equal (appear more than once in the list). Using MoreLINQ, the code below is working:

```
var list = new List<LinqTest> // LinqTest: object containing 2 strings
{
    // are ok
    new LinqTest { Str1 = "a1", Str2 = "b1"},
    new LinqTest { Str1 = "a2", Str2 = "b2"},
    new LinqTest { Str1 = "a3", Str2 = "b3"},
    new LinqTest { Str1 = "a5", Str2 = "b5"},
    new LinqTest { Str1 = "a6", Str2 = "b6"},
    new LinqTest { Str1 = "x1", Str2 = "y1"},
    new LinqTest { Str1 = "y1", Str2 = "x1"},

    // must be removed
    new LinqTest { Str1 = "d1", Str2 = "b4"},
    new LinqTest { Str1 = "d1", Str2 = "d2"},
    new LinqTest { Str1 = "d1", Str2 = "d2"},
    new LinqTest { Str1 = "a4", Str2 = "d2"},
    new LinqTest { Str1 = "d3", Str2 = "b7"},
    new LinqTest { Str1 = "d3", Str2 = "b8"},
    new LinqTest { Str1 = "d3", Str2 = "b8"},
};

var duplicatesStr1 = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.Str1)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToList();

var duplicatesStr2 = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.Str2)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToList(); ;

var res = list
    .ExceptBy(duplicatesStr1, x => x.Str1)
    .ExceptBy(duplicatesStr2, x => x.Str2);

var rem = duplicatesStr1
    .Union(duplicatesStr2)
    .DistinctBy(x => new { x.Str1, x.Str2})
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine("----------");
foreach (var linqTest in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine("keep> " + linqTest.Str1 + "-" + linqTest.Str2);
}

Console.WriteLine("----------");
foreach (var linqTest in rem)
{
    Console.WriteLine("remove> " + linqTest.Str1 + "-" + linqTest.Str2);
}
```

**Question:**
Is there a more efficient and/or shorter way to achieve this?

Comment: Better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do two passes by first getting all the values that exist for the first and second properties more than once, and then filter on that.  You'd need 2 hash sets for each property.  The first one is to keep track if a value has been seen at least once.  And if it has been seen at least once it's then added to the second hash set.  Thus resulting in one hash set for each property that only contains the values that are duplicated.  Then just filter out any items that are in either of those hash sets.

```
HashSet<string> hash1Once = new HashSet<string>();
HashSet<string> hash1More = new HashSet<string>();
HashSet<string> hash2Once = new HashSet<string>();
HashSet<string> hash2More = new HashSet<string>();

foreach(var item in list){
    if(!hash1Once.Add(item.Str1))
        hash1More.Add(item.Str1);
    if(!hash2Once.Add(item.Str2))
        hash2More.Add(item.Str2);
}

var unique = list.Where(x => !hash1More.Contains(x.Str1) && !hash2More.Contains(x.Str2))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Works and is faster than mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`.Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx) LINQ method to do this. You'll have to define a custom [`IEqualityComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to decide when two elements are considered distinct.

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<LinqTest>
{
    public bool Equals(LinqTest x, LinqTest y)
    {
        return x.Str1 == y.Str1 || x.Str2 == y.Str2;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(LinqTest obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
List<LinqTest> noDuplicates = originalList.Distinct(new MyComparer()).ToList();
```

The tricky part is part is implementing the [`IEqualityComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) properly (and I didn't the first time around!). `GetHashCode()` must return the same value for two objects that are considered equal. Since our notion of equality is not transitive, the only way to satisfy this requirement is to return a constant value. This is allowed, but defeats the goal of the hash codes, which are a way to speed up equality checking: if the hash codes differ, the objects must differ without needing potentially more costly "deep" comparison.

So, this code works, but does not achieve the highest possible performance.

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: Couldn't two equal items end up with different hash codes?  I'm pretty sure that hash code algorithm is meant for when equality is based on and'ing, not or'ing.

Comment: @juharr That is true. I suppose you could defeat the hash altogether by always returning a constant. I'm curious now whether the `Distinct()` implementation even uses `GetHashCode()` (if not it doesn't matter, if so there will be a performance impact). The notion of equality in use here is also not transitive, i.e. it is possible to have `Equals(a, b)` and `Equals(b, c)` but `!Equals(a, c)`.

Comment: If you check the code it uses the hash to create buckets to put equal items into to speed up checking if a value was seen. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

Comment: I can't think of any alternative than to return a constant hash value, and I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Then you're left with a solution that likely would be slower.  Additionally just using `Distinct` like that would keep at least one of the "duplicate" items (more because the equality isn't transitive), but the OP wants to remove all items that are considered duplicates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163440/discussion-between-typeia-and-juharr).

Comment: To be clear since people are still up voting this if you have items a, b, and c where a == b and b == c, but a != c then this could decide to keep a, then discard b because it's equal to a, but then keep c because it's not equal to a and it's not compared to b because it was discarded.

Comment: @juharr That is true and worthwhile to note but it's not clear that this isn't what the OP expects in this situation. I'm starting to feel there may be a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. If we knew more about the data and the intended behavior of that data I think we could come up with a better answer.

Comment: @TypeIA Thanks for your answers. Trying to clarify, data is as in the sample: one object with 2 string properties that can have any value. Objective is: remove all objects for which at least one of the property values appears more than once for that property. Result: list with objects to keep. Your answer keeps {d1, b4} but d1 appears 3 times in Str1. Updated sample to print result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using standard LINQ ToDictionary() method to remove items that are duplicated based on property comparison. Create a dictionary that accumulates the count of matches throughout the list, and filter the resulting dictionary for those with a single match.

```
        list = list.ToDictionary(
                test => test,
                test => list.Count(item => item.Str1 == test.Str1 || item.Str2 == test.Str2)
            ).Where(pair => pair.Value == 1)
            .Select(pair => pair.Key)
            .ToList();
```

Even better would be to create an extension method in a separate class and push the unique property comparison logic to there.

```
internal static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Unique<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> sequence,
        Func<T, T, bool> match)
    {
        var list = sequence.ToList();
        return list
            .ToDictionary(arg => arg, arg => list.Count(item => match(item, arg)))
            .Where(pair => pair.Value == 1)
            .Select(pair => pair.Key);
    }
}
```

Exposed as an extension method would result in a method signature of:

```
list = list.Unique((a, b) => a.Str1 == b.Str1 || a.Str2 == b.Str2).ToList();
```

Comment: Works, but is much slower.